# Is there a Windows 3.11 WPF style? If not, how can I draw some?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, styling, windows-3.1

For some retro application I'm currently planning, I'd need some Windows 3.11 style for WPF. Has anyone done some yet? If this is not the case, how can I make one? I never tried that. I, especially, need a Win3.1-styled menu, toolbar, and button widget.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can style all of these elements using WPF with the style attribute. Useful information for you can be found [in this tutorial](http://wpftutorial.net/Styles.html) or [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675255/applying-a-wpf-style-to-multiple-controls). Additionaly you can add a style to the resources of the `Application` to apply them to really all items of a particular class in your entire application.

In your **App.xaml**:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I do not know any Windows 3.11 Style yet, but maybe you get along building your own one.

Comment: Hm, thanks. Looks like some work. But I can work with that. :)